# Not able to add DB in Redis-insight for Redis-stack-server cluster for more than one master node

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, redis-stack-server, redis-stack

We have deployed the Redis-stack-server cluster in Kubernetes. We are able to create DB (mean add DB in Redis-insight) for Redis-stack-server cluster for one master node but when we increase the master nodes (more than one) than we are not able to create DB

I have provided the basic config details please let me know if yo need any specific info

config.yaml

```
        requirepass password
        masterauth password
        cluster-enabled yes
        cluster-require-full-coverage no
        cluster-node-timeout 15000
        cluster-config-file /data/nodes.conf
        cluster-migration-barrier 1
        appendonly yes
        dir /var/lib/redis/data
        protected-mode no
```

Service.yaml

```
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 6379
      targetPort: 6379
      name: client
    - port: 16379
      targetPort: 16379
      name: gossip
```

Stateful.yaml

```
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: redis
          image: redis/redis-stack-server:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 6379
              name: client
            - containerPort: 16379
              name: gossip
          command: ["/usr/local/etc/redis/update-node.sh", "redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
          env:
            - name: POD_IP
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: status.podIP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: configmap-redis-cache
              mountPath: /usr/local/etc/redis/
              #mountPath: /conf
              readOnly: false
            - name: data
              mountPath: /data
              readOnly: false
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 1000
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
            readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - KILL
                - MKNOD
                - SYS_CHROOT
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: '1'
              memory: 2Gi
            requests:
              cpu: '1'
              memory: 2Gi
          livenessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: redis
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 5
            failureThreshold: 5
            successThreshold: 1
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - redis-cli
                - ping
            initialDelaySeconds: 20
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 3
      volumes:
        - name: configmap-redis-cache
          configMap:
            name: configmap-redis-cache
            defaultMode: 0755
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: data
      spec:
        accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
        storageClassName: "nas-thin"
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 200Mi
```

Docker File

```
FROM docker.repo1.uhc.com/redis/redis-stack-server:latest

RUN mkdir -p /var/lib/redis/data && chown -R 1001:1001 /var/lib/redis/data && chmod -R 777 /var/lib/redis/data

USER 999
```